# JS script embedded in another website works with safari but do not work with chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a JS script embedded in another website. the target is to gram field contact and post it.
my problem is that the script runs well on safari browser but not with chrome browser.

I tried:
-clear cache on browsers

- clear server Cache
- clear Cloudflare Cache
- checked that the file is reachable
- no error on console

also tried to put alert to see the script is running. works of safari and do not show the alert in chrome even in incognito mode

here is the code:

```js
var API_KEY = "key";
var API_DOMAIN = location.hostname;
var TOKEN = getParameterByName('token');

console.log('params');
console.log(API_DOMAIN);
console.log(TOKEN);


var reg_emailInputId = document.getElementById('reg_email');
// on keyup, start the countdown 
reg_emailInputId.onfocusout = function() {
  // init 
  var isValid = validateEmail(reg_emailInputId.value);

  // check if token is not empty 
  if ((TOKEN !== '' || TOKEN !== null) && isValid === true) {
    doneTyping(reg_emailInputId.value, '107');
  }
  console.log('listener_on');
};


function doneTyping(myInputValue, id) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(xhttp.responseText);
      console.log('send params');

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "domain", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send(params);

}

function getParameterByName(name, url = window.location.href) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\$&');
  var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

function validateEmail(email) {
  // init 
  var mailformat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;

  // check 
  if (email.match(mailformat)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="reg_email" >
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the target is to gram field contact` ?? `reg_emailInputId.onfocusout = function() {` does not get triggered in Chrome

Comment: js needs to have sha hash when included using script tag

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen ???

Comment: have a look at [this](https://content-security-policy.com/hash/)

Comment: and [this](https://content-security-policy.com/script-src/)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Where is this question tagged CSP?

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen see my [second example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69866799/295783)

Comment: where is alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reg_emailInputId.onfocusout = function() {` is not triggered in Chrome

Use an eventListener

```js
var API_KEY = "key";
var API_DOMAIN = location.hostname;
var TOKEN = getParameterByName('token');

console.log('params');
console.log(API_DOMAIN);
console.log(TOKEN);


var reg_emailInputId = document.getElementById('reg_email');
// on keyup, start the countdown 
reg_emailInputId.addEventListener("focusout", function() {
  // init 
  var isValid = validateEmail(reg_emailInputId.value);

  // check if token is not empty 
  if ((TOKEN !== '' || TOKEN !== null) && isValid === true) {
    doneTyping(reg_emailInputId.value, '107');
  }
  console.log('listener_on');
});


function doneTyping(myInputValue, id) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(xhttp.responseText);
      console.log('send params');

    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "domain", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send(params);

}

function getParameterByName(name, url = window.location.href) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\$&');
  var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

function validateEmail(email) {
  // init 
  var mailformat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;

  // check 
  if (email.match(mailformat)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="reg_email" >
```

Especially for Dean:

```html
<input type="text" id="reg_email" >
<script src="https://plungjan.name/SO/formval.js"></script>
```

Comment: tnx, that's solved the problem